# Windowsフォルダ内のファイルを(ユーザー操作することなく)JavaScriptで自動読み込みしたい

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file

**最終的にやりたいこと(概要)**
「JavaScriptを使用した画像編集(canvasタグ使用)」を自動化したい
※Windows環境でバッチ処理化

**最終的にやりたいこと(処理フロー)**
1.Windows内のaフォルダへ複数画像ファイル配置
2.(ユーザー操作することなく)JavaScriptでファイル自動読込
3.JavaScriptで画像処理後、canvasタグへ描画
4.canvasタグより取得した画像ファイルを、Windows内のzフォルダへ出力

**分からないこと**
(ユーザー操作することなく)JavaScriptでWindows内の指定フォルダにあるファイルを自動読込する方法はありますか？
・WindowsでJavaScript(canvasタグ)が使用できる方法の中で、上記が可能なものはありますか？ 
・ヘッドレスブラウザを使用すれば可能？

**補足**
Windows環境でJavaScriptが使用できる方法なら、何でも良いです。ブラウザでフォルダ選択するだけの作業を、自動化したいと思い質問しました

Answer (score 2):

耳慣れない言葉ですが、ヘッドレスブラウザなら可能だと思います。
Node.jsならWindows内のフォルダへファイル出力できます。
Puppeteerでヘッドレスブラウザを試してみてはいかがでしょうか。